# How to update an attribute dynamically set in JSP PageContext?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Please correct me if I am wrong. I am developing a small web application for learning purpose. I have a `jsp` in which a list of top scorers in the the game are to be displayed in a table. For that I wrote a `ServletContextListener` and in the `contextInitialized()` method I have set an attribute(`LinkedHashSet`) in the `ContextScope`, which is the list of top 10 scorers in the game. I think it can be accessed using `EL`. But how can I update this collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("your_attribute_name_here")` and can access the LinkedHashSet, once you get it you can add/remove/update values in it and again set it back to put updated values like `request.getSession().getServletContext().setAttribute("your_attribute_name_here", "update_LinkedHashSet");` As best of my knowledge using EL you can access it but can not put back the updated value in attribute.

Note: while accessing the attribute you will need the explicit type casting.

Answer (score 0):

You can update attribute like :

```
    <%((Set<String>)pageContext.getServletContext().getAttribute("set")).add("Second"); %>
    <% Set<String> set = (Set<String>) pageContext.getServletContext().getAttribute("set"); %>
    from servlet context
        <c:forEach items="${set}" var="s">
          <c:out value="${s}"/>
        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: I think usage of java code in JSP should be avoided.

Comment: yes right. It's just for an example you can update in servlet also like request.getServletContext().getAttribute("set"); and perform updation.